# Create/Update database for One new Entity

Tags: php, entity-framework, doctrine-orm, migration, symfony4

I have yet some Entity in relation with a database working fine. 
I've create one new Entity: Newentity.php

I want to create the table newentity in my database without touch anything more.

The only way it works for me is deleting (after saving, of course) all table from the database and writing:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:create
```

Doing:

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
```

Give me this error:

```
Compile Error: Cannot declare class App\Entity\JosMenu, because the name is already in use
```

JosMenu is my first Entity.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try it:

```
namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="jos_menu_2") //here your table name
 */
class JosMenu
{
***************************************************************
```

And check other Entities name may be already exist

Comment: It's just that. I had one backup folder inside the Entity folder with all my working Entitys. I'd move this folder out symfony's proyect and  now "php bin/console doctrine:schema:update" works fine. Thanks Imanali